# Collapsive rows don't work after using router-link

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have another problem with Vue.js. I've created this structure of table:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                Open
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropdown">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is `js` script:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.label').click(function() {
        $(this).parents().next('.dropdown').toggle();
    });
})
```

Also I have another component. When I open it using `router-link` and then come back to the main component, dropdown rows don't work. When I reload an application, they work again.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: where did you bind the click event?  created function or ??

Comment: @Bravo No, I haven't any errors

Comment: @LLIaJIyH Try wrapping the `<router-view>` with [`<keep-alive>` component](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view). Also, why jQuery for the dropdown effect?

Comment: @AirNoir No, I bind it in the `index.html` in the end of `body'

Comment: @YomS. I can use clean js, but Jquery is shorter and more comfortable for me.

Comment: @YomS. Thanks, `<keep-alive>` helped!

Comment: When the routes change, the child component will be destroyed. I guess the event is removed when you change view.